# Laravel Session and Cache Read/Write Driver

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-session, laravel-cache

I would like to use different connection for reading and writing to session and cache.
I am using redis as cache and session storage.

Here are my env configs :

```
REDIS_HOST=192.168.1.230
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

REDIS_HOST_READ=192.168.1.13
REDIS_PASSWORD_READ=null
REDIS_PORT_READ=6380

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
```

My cache.php(config/cache.php) modifications :

```
'stores' => [ 
    'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],
        
        'redis-read' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'read',
        ]
]
```

My database.php(config/database.php) modifications :

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'phpredis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'persistent'=> 1
        ],

        'session' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
            'persistent'=> 1
        ],

        'read' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST_READ', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD_READ', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT_READ', 6380),
            'database' => 0,
            'persistent'=> 1
        ],

    ],
```

I am able to read from redis read host as follows :

```
Cache::driver('redis-read')->get('general_data');
```

But I don't want to define this every time when I am reading cache/session.
Is there any other way to do this ? I mean whenever I am reading cache/session, it will use "redis-read" and whenever I am writing to cache/session, it will use "redis".

Comment: you can set the default cache driver `CACHE_DRIVER` in the `.env` file, so you don't nee to define the driver every time.

Comment: Yes @FaizanAli. I need to use both redis and redis-read.
redis-read for reading only and redis for writing.